# Model doesn’t show in admin

Tags: python, django

I am currently working on a science django blog. I've finished coding it all and I realized that the models items overview and content don't appear in my django.admin. Here's an image so you can see.
[image]

I know there are other threads related to it. However, I couldn't find the solution in those.

Models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    overview = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = HTMLField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    featured = models.BooleanField()
    previous_post = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', related_name='previous', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    next_post = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', related_name='next', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

Admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Author, Category, Post, Comment, PostView
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Author)
admin.site.register(Category)
admin.site.register(Post)
```

Settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',

    'crispy_forms',
    'tinymce',

    'marketing',
    'posts'
]
```

And urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

By the way, the models.py is in the app Posts. Just in case somebody needs this information.

The other models work perfectly. It’s just the overview and the content

Comment: Did you make migrations after add these fields ?

Comment: Add Url and migrate...Docs :- https://django-tinymce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html. Test your HTMLField :- http://localhost:8000/admin/testapp/testpage/add/

Comment: Yes, I made migrations and migrated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :-

```
content = models.TextField()
```

Instead of :-

```
content = HTMLField()
```

AND then make migrations, migrate

Comment: I’ll do that. The problem is I needed tinymce in order to write posts.

Comment: @Marcgames_YT If you need to write posts in django admin.Use django-ckeditor 6.0.0 . it's best..For more detail Docs :- https://pypi.org/project/django-ckeditor/#installation

Comment: I've just uplodaded it. It's much better than TinyMCE. Thanks for telling me